# convert array to have all same keys

Tags: php

I need all keys of an array to be the same. I know with php they can't, but I am trying to send an array to soap.

My array Looks like this.

```
array(     
[0] => Array
    (
        [SKU] => Special Day
        [Description] => Special Day
        [Quantity] => 3
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [SKU] => The Legend Continues
        [Description] => The Legend Continues
        [Quantity] => 7
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [SKU] => Blank Inside
        [Description] => Blank Inside
        [Quantity] => 1
    )
)
```

I am in need of this.

```
$auth = array(

'Shipment' => array(
  'Items' => array( 

      'Item'=> Array
       (
        [SKU] => Special Day
        [Description] => Special Day
        [Quantity] => 3
        )

       'Item' => Array
        (
        [SKU] => The Legend Continues
        [Description] => The Legend Continues
        [Quantity] => 7
        )

      'Item' => Array
       (
        [SKU] => Blank Inside
        [Description] => Blank Inside
        [Quantity] => 1
       )
   )
)
```

How can I turn the loop that makes the arrays into what i need?

I am using this to make the arrays now.

```
while (wpsc_have_cart_items()) : wpsc_the_cart_item(); 
    $items[] = array(
        'SKU' => wpsc_cart_item_name(),
        'Description' => wpsc_cart_item_name(),
        'Quantity' => wpsc_cart_item_quantity()
    );
endwhile;
```

Comment: we can not use same key `Item` for array it should be `Item-1, Item-2, Item-3` etc

Comment: I'm not familiar with SOAP programming, but I doubt it requires this.

Comment: It is not possible with PHP. Do you want to convert it to XML before sending it to SOAP.

Comment: Yea I guess I am going to need to do that.

Comment: How would I do that when doing a loop?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml, it offers a few ways to do it.